# Why laravel queries appear on browser

Tags: laravel

yesterday I made some test on my localhost on a website with Laravel. And I saw some queries that I executed on my text editor (Sublime Text) appear on browser. I never seen like that before. [I took with capture tool image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YrmL.png)
Sorry if I made some mistake on my post, I'm a biginner learning english and programmation. Someone could help me please to understand that!

Comment: add your code which you wrote to the post for better help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is shown because it is an error, and it is used for debugging purposes, on your local machine, so in your `.env` file you have this

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

Change that to

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

and you won't see the query, but then it will be hard for you to develop, so it is good to have this flag as true on your local machine, once you push the code to production you would want that flag to be `false` and read the `storage/logs` files instead in case an error occurs.

Comment: After do changes in the .env file please run " php artisan config:clear ".

Comment: Yes, I had my .env file exactly like that with APP_DEBUG=true for showing errors which will occur througout my test on localhost. Thank's, I fixed settings and it's work.